# Alguna manera de hacer que querys se devuelvan en json?

Tags: python, json, django, djangorestframework

Estoy buscando alguna manera de hacer que mi codigo al momento de enviar un **"GET"** con **postman** me devuelva algunas querys que tengo en la BD pero en forma de archivo **json**,
Al momento de mandar el GET a postman al server lo unico que me devuelve es el mismo archivo html o me deja agregar cosas a la **BD**
Necesito Mandar un Get que unicamente me traiga el json de el listar o de los clientes, productos, etc- Como podria hacerlo, ya me he quedado sin ideas y al ver tutoriales ya tienen otras cosas ahi. Mi codigo esta muy avanzado para empezar otra vez :(

Alguna idea? Muchas gracias! dejo parte del codigo...

```
import json
from typing import Container
from website.serializer import ProductoSerializer
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core.serializers import serialize
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http.response import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse, JsonResponse
from django.views.generic import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView, ListView, TemplateView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from .models import Cliente, Producto
from django import forms
from django.views import generic
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from rest_framework import status
from django.core.serializers import serialize

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'website/home.html')

def clientes(request):
    return render(request, 'website/clientes.html')   

# vista instrumentos
def producto(request):
    return render(request, 'website/producto.html')

def otros(request):
    return render(request, 'website/otros.html')


class ClienteCreate(CreateView):
        model = Cliente
        #form_class = clientes
        fields = '__all__'
        template_name = 'website/cliente_form.html'
        success_url = reverse_lazy('clientes_list')

class ClienteUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Cliente
    #fields = ['nombre','telefono','email','direccion','usuario','contrasenia']    
    fields = '__all__'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('clientes_list')

class ClienteDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Cliente
    success_url = reverse_lazy('clientes_list')

class ClienteDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Cliente    

class ClienteListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Cliente
    template_name = 'website/clientes_list.html'

#Producto CRUD
class ProductoCreate(CreateView):
    model = Producto
    fields = '__all__'
    template_name = 'website/producto_form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('producto_list')
  
class ProductoUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Producto
    #fields = ['nombre','telefono','email','direccion','usuario','contrasenia']    
    fields = '__all__'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('producto_list')

class ProductoDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Producto
    success_url = reverse_lazy('producto_list')

class ProductoDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Producto    

class ProductoListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Producto
    template_name = 'website/producto_list.html'

@csrf_exempt
def ProductListView(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        customers = producto.objects.all()
        customers_serializer = ProductoSerializer(customers, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(customers_serializer.data, safe=False)
        # In order to serialize objects, we must set 'safe=False'

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        customer_data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        customer_serializer = ProductoSerializer(data=customer_data)
        if customer_serializer.is_valid():
            customer_serializer.save() 
            return JsonResponse(customer_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED) 
        return JsonResponse(customer_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


@csrf_exempt 
def ProductDetailView(request, pk):
    try: 
        customer = Producto.objects.get(pk=pk) 
    except Producto.DoesNotExist: 
        return HttpResponse(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND) 
 
    if request.method == 'GET': 
        customer_serializer = ProductoSerializer(customer) 
        return JsonResponse(customer_serializer.data) 
 
    elif request.method == 'PUT': 
        customer_data = JSONParser().parse(request) 
        customer_serializer = ProductoSerializer(customer, data=customer_data) 
        if customer_serializer.is_valid(): 
            customer_serializer.save() 
            return JsonResponse(customer_serializer.data) 
        return JsonResponse(customer_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST) 
 
    elif request.method == 'DELETE': 
        customer.delete() 
        return HttpResponse(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Busque alguna maneras de hacerlo con el mismo Django, pero la verdad soy muy novato y no logro cranear una manera de hacerlo, Lo intente con serializer pero no arroja nada y arruino el codigo simplemente, alguna manera de hacerlo con los views?

Comment: si la petición lo haces a una ruta que renderiza un HTML, tendrias que retornar un JSON en vez del HTML. Otra cosa es que no muestras a que ruta estas haciendo la petición

Comment: Hola! Estaba ocupando "localhost/website/producto/list" para los demas es casi lo mismo cambia un poco la ruta

Answer (score 0):

Dado que estás usando DRF lo más sencillo sería crear la vista con una APIView:

```
from .models import Cliente, Producto
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response


class ProductoList(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        data = Producto.objects.all()
        return Response(data.values())
```

Recuerda añadir la ruta que apunte a la vista en urls.py:

```
from website.views import ProductoList

urlpatterns = [
    # aquí irían el resto de urls declaradas
    path('producto/list', ProductoList.as_view())
]
```